# What is the proper way to amend code on another user's pull-request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

### Scenario

If `User X` maintains a repo, and `User A` submits a pull-request, I want, as `User B` to suggest cleanup or additional features on top of that pull-request.

### What I'm doing

The way I'm doing it is fetch `User A`'s repo and feature branch, update the code and submit a stand alone pull-request to `User X`.

### Question

But the above feels a little douchebaggy and wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a separate pull-request to UserA's feature branch. If he accepts it, your commits will be added to the original pull-request.

You can also refer to the original pull request in the new one so it shows up in a comment on Github.

If he doesn't accept the pull request, go the douchebaggy way. His commits will still show up as his own, so it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to not use pull requests at all. That's why the Git project doesn't use pull requests for development, instead, each patch series is sent to the mailing list, where it's easy to review each patch, then the original author fixes the issues and sends a re-roll of the series, which receives more reviews and so on. It's not unusual for each patch series to re-roll multiple times.

That's the main reason Linus Torvalds didn't like the whole GitHub approach.

That being said, you can review patches in Github, and request the original author to send another pull-request.

As a last resort, what I do is that I manually add the `User A` remote to my local repo, fetch, and fix the commits myself, adding an appropriate comment, or adding new separate commits, and then merge my local branch, not the remote one.

Comment: The fixed code will be seen when the user fetches your repo. And no, it won't be in his pull request, his pull request will have what he requested to pull.

Comment: You cannot do what is not possible. In GitHub and everywhere, User A's pull's request is User A's pull request and contains User A's pull request.

Comment: Yeah, but you cannot do that. Your pull request is different from his, he has to accept your pull request, and then send a new one, his pull request will remain the same. You can add comments in his pull request, but it doesn't get updated.

Comment: Yes, in GitHub it might be, but he is pulling your fixes, that would appear as a merge on top of his changes, and you pull his, you would have a merge of a merge, which you can achieve locally anyway.

Comment: I feel like we can clean up the question from our spammy comments continue this discussion [in a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39201/what-is-the-proper-way-to-amend-code-on-another-users-pull-request). I've transcribed the comments above, so feel free to delete yours (i'm deleting mine)

Answer (score 0):

2017 update:

Github now [allows pushing changes](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/) to the branch the pull request was made from, if the commiter allows it.

When creating a pull request there is now an option to: "Allow edits from maintainers". It's checked by default.

Comment: Whoever has a commit bit, I suppose.